# Is there a difference between an empty key and a key that doesn't exist?

Tags: cassandra, hector

When using a MultigetSliceQuery, the results will contain a row for each key, even if the key doesn't exist. The only way to test might be to check if any columns exist for each row.

But, if I create a row with 1 or more columns and then delete all the columns, the result from MultigetSliceQuery will be the same (as if the row was never created in the first place).

When testing this with the CLI, "**list CF**" will show the empty row key, but "**get CF[key]**" will return "*Returned 0 results.*"

Is a Row without any Columns valid?

Should there be a way to check the results for empty vs exists?

Answer (score 3):

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts

If you do a MultigetSlice, and enumerate the keys it will return a result for each key.

In the case of the cli see

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DistributedDeletes

The empty rows actually have tombstones in them for the deleted columns.

If you attempt to retrieve an entire row and it returns a result with no columns, it effectively means that row does not exist.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with tombstones, as I not deleting the keys, just all the columns. And I'm testing on single node, with GCGraceSeconds=0. But, in the end, there is no difference between a non-existent row, and a row with no columns.

Comment: Tombstones exist per column, so you would have a tombstone for each column that was deleted. Also, even with GCGraceSeconds=0, a compaction would have to occure before the tombstones are removed.

Comment: While the tombstones may exists (after delete), they have no impact on my row scan (in my question). Assuming consistency, I find that the row scan will show all keys, including those have been deleted (either directly or by removing all columns). I also found that after deleting rows (by key) that don't actually exist, the row scan will now list those keys! (so no tombstones there).

Comment: To clarify, there are both per-column and per-row tombstones.  When you do delete a row (whether it exists or not doesn't matter -- Cassandra doesn't check to see if it exists), a tombstone is blindly written for that row, so the tombstone will then show up in range scans.